# Using sharp with discordie on Node.js, old images appear in output on subsequent runs, where's the damage?

Tags: node.js, discord

I run a discordie based discord bot on Node.js with the sharp node module for the use of resizing of images.
For some reason everytime the command is executed the image used remains and will be reused if the command is used again (only if the types match). Transparent pngs get overwritten by the first transparent png, non transparent pngs by their first used counterpart and JPGs by theirs.

I have no idea why this happens as on the fs side of things the image is properly downloaded, only the output file from sharp will show this strange behaviour.

If anyone knows what might cause this I'm pretty much out of ideas.

Rebooting the bot (exiting the node process) as expected will clear the issue until the next time the command is used more than once.

```
function isNum(value)
{
    return "number" == typeof value && !isNaN(value);
}
Commands.push(
{
    name: 'sharp',
    help: 'Image resizing, \"-sharp link\"; or \"-sharp link width height\". If you only define width height will be the same as width.',
    level: 0,
    hidden: false,
    fn: function(msg, suffix, bot)
    {
        console.log("Image Upload:")
        //Dimension Code
        let x;
        let y;
        switch (suffix.split(" ").length)
        {
            case 1:
                x = 280;
                y = 280;
                break;
            case 2:
                x = suffix.split(" ")[1];
                y = suffix.split(" ")[1]
                break;
            case 3:
                x = suffix.split(" ")[1];
                y = suffix.split(" ")[2]
                break;
        }
        suffix = suffix.split(" ")[0]
        //File upload handling
        if (!msg.attachments[0])
        {
            console.log("using URL")
        }
        else
        {
            let suffix = msg.attachments[0].proxy_url;
            console.log("using FILE");
            x = 280;
            y = 280;
        }
        x = parseInt(x);
        y = parseInt(y);
        //Validation of dimensions
        if (!isNum(x) || !isNum(y) || y < 1 || x < 1 || x > 2000 || y > 2000)
        {
            return msg.reply("Error invalid sizes!\nSize can not be 0 or bigger than 2000")
        }
        let imgdir = "C:/test/";
        suffix = suffix.replace("<", "").replace(">", "")
        let ext = "." + suffix.split("")[suffix.split("").length - 3] + suffix.split("")[suffix.split("").length - 2] + suffix.split("")[suffix.split("").length - 1]
        let filename = msg.author.id + ext;
        //Validation of file ending. (Technically we dont need one but this is to try and make sure people give correct links)
        if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".png")
        {}
        else
        {
            return msg.reply("Only links and files ending in png or jpg are supported. Attempted file ext: " + ext)
        }
        //Start Stream/Axios Async
        async function downloadImage()
        {
            console.log("writing")
            let url = suffix
            let path = Path.resolve(imgdir, 'images', filename)
            let writer = fs.createWriteStream(path)
            console.log(url, path)
            const response = await axios(
            {
                url,
                method: 'GET',
                responseType: 'stream'
            })
            response.data.pipe(writer)
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
            {
                writer.on('finish', resolve =>
                {
                    sharp(path).resize(x, y,
                    {
                        fit: 'fill'
                    }).toFile(path + "output", (err, info) =>
                    {
                        if (err)
                        {
                            CM(logchannel, err)
                        }
                        if (err)
                        {
                            return
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            msg.channel.uploadFile(path + "output");
                        }
                    })
                })
                writer.on('error', reject)
            })
        }
        downloadImage()
        console.log("Upload finished.")
    }
})
```

Edit: making each input file unique in name avoids the issue.

added 'let uti=Date.now()' to path.

Comment: You should probably add a random string, or the current time, to that temporary filename.

Comment: @AKX going to attempt this real quick, didn't assume it would be an issue based on how the input file updates properly, will give it a shot tho.

Comment: By the way, you should probably use `path.extname()` to extract the extension from a path string. :)

Comment: @AKX Thanks a lot for the path extname() suggestion, had no idea path could do this.

As for your suggestion of giving each input file a uid via timestamp, it actually works... which doesn't fix the underlying issue of the images not clearing after usage but hey, at least it works as intended now!